# Efficiency and timeout for network servers

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, timeout, semaphore

I'm in a situation where I have to "ping" [not ICMP] (by ping I mean, use an application protocol I made in order to signal multiple sockets to see if they have died or not [similar to a watchdog timer]).

Since I was limited to asynchronous selecting in my library (bound to a window message loop), I decided to improve it's efficiency by instead of receiving the data directly by the GUI messages - to forward it to a threadpool via a data structure and let a queue of threads handle it.

Right, my initial idea was to use 2 semaphores - one to handle a blocking queue (of IO requests) and another semaphore to handle all the timeout pings.

Does this seem like a reasonable idea? Is there a better solution; perhaps a timer, mutex or something else?

A second question that I might ask would be - apart from a synchronization object, is there any other way I can create a blocking container? I'm not accepting Sleep(1) solutions by the way.
Thank you.

Comment: Hmm.. does your semaphore class have a wait with a timeout?

Comment: Yes it does and I confirm that the whole problem "can" be solved with a semaphore and it works fine. I'm looking for an alternative since I believe there's a better solution.